# How to convert a type of a string field to array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a field in a document whose type is `string`, like below:

```
{
_id:ObjectId("632c12d98b4d9347774a4e9f"),
keyword:'keyword1'
}
```

I want to change it to below:

```
{
_id:ObjectId("632c12d98b4d9347774a4e9f"),
keyword:['keyword1']
}
```

How can I do it in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an update pipeline:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {$set: {keyword: ["$keyword"]}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gRXFrpbyg90)